# Converting Map coordinates to Screen

Tags: java, geotools

I am trying to convert world coordinates to pixel coordinates. The problem is, some files (shapefiles) do not convert as it should. The lines are slanted or moved, they should look exactly as when I load the file for display.

The reason I am converting the lines is because it needs to display in Adobe Illustrator, and normal map coordinates are much to large to display properly.

Is there a better way to convert world coordinates to screen coordinates more reliably?
(the convertLines method is where all the conversion is happening)

```
    ArrayList<FeatureLine> temp = new ArrayList();

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        MCV_TestProgram test = new MCV_TestProgram();
    }

    public MCV_TestProgram() {
        temp.add(new FeatureLine("2466308.97 709571.48, 2466306.03 709566.79", 0));
        temp.add(new FeatureLine("2466800.14 710357.15, 2466308.97 709571.48", 1));
        temp.add(new FeatureLine("2456506.25 707356.2, 2456487.75 707715.23, 2456450.68 707809.01", 2));
        temp.add(new FeatureLine("2324352.2 669626.61, 2324365.6 669328.81, 2324146.77 669316.22, 2324165.41 669264.1, 2324174.26 669057.93, 2324192.39 668895.68, 2324211.04 668561.95, 2324219.11 668494.04, 2324230.7 668370.9, 2324247.66 668128.16, 2324260.89 667951.94, 2324268.86 667848.91, 2324278.83 667705.33, 2324289.97 667508.67", 3));

        convertLines(temp);
    }

    // Converts map lines to fit in smaller window (mainly for Adobe Illustrator)
    private ArrayList<FeatureLine> convertLines(ArrayList<FeatureLine> lines) {
        ArrayList<FeatureLine> convertedCoords = new ArrayList();

        try {
            Rectangle imageBounds = new Rectangle(250, 200, 1000, 800);
            CoordinateReferenceSystem crs = createCRS();
            ReferencedEnvelope mapBounds = new ReferencedEnvelope(2104208.77, 2595754.33, 500627.08, 1286916.23, crs);
            AffineTransform world2screen = createTransform(mapBounds, imageBounds);

            for (FeatureLine coord : lines) {
                Point2D screenCoordStart = world2screen.transform(coord.StartPoint, null);
                Point2D screenCoordEnd = world2screen.transform(coord.EndPoint, null);

                if (coord.StartPoint.x != 0.0) {
                    convertedCoords.add(new FeatureLine(screenCoordStart, screenCoordEnd));
                }
            }
        } catch (FactoryException | MismatchedDimensionException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(MCV_TestProgram.class.getSimpleName()).log(Level.SEVERE, "Error occured while converting lines", ex);
        }

        return convertedCoords;
    }

    // Custom line class to store line data, StartPoint and Endpoint (coordinates)
    // of one unbreaking line.
    public class FeatureLine {

        private Point2D.Double StartPoint = new Point2D.Double();
        private Point2D.Double EndPoint = new Point2D.Double();

        public FeatureLine(double x1, double y1, double x2, double y2) {
            StartPoint.x = x1;
            StartPoint.y = y1;
            EndPoint.x = x2;
            EndPoint.y = y2;
        }

        public FeatureLine(Point2D.Double start, Point2D.Double end) {
            StartPoint = start;
            EndPoint = end;
        }

        public FeatureLine(Point2D start, Point2D end) {
            StartPoint = (Point2D.Double) start;
            EndPoint = (Point2D.Double) end;
        }

        public FeatureLine(String parseString, int index) {

            String latlon[];
            String xy1[];
            String xy2[];

            double x1, y1;
            double x2, y2;

            try {
                if (!parseString.equals("")) {
                    latlon = parseString.split(",");

                    xy1 = latlon[0].split(" ");
                    xy2 = latlon[1].replaceFirst(" ", "").split(" ");

                    x1 = Double.parseDouble(xy1[0]);
                    y1 = Double.parseDouble(xy1[1]);

                    x2 = Double.parseDouble(xy2[0]);
                    y2 = Double.parseDouble(xy2[1]);

                    StartPoint.x = x1;
                    StartPoint.y = y1;

                    EndPoint.x = x2;
                    EndPoint.y = y2;
                }
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                logger.log(Level.SEVERE, "Error occured while creating line at: " + index + " ", ex);
            }
        }

        public double getX(int index) {
            if (index == 0) {
                return StartPoint.x;
            } else {
                return EndPoint.x;
            }
        }

        public double getY(int index) {
            if (index == 0) {
                return StartPoint.y;
            } else {
                return EndPoint.y;
            }
        }

        public void setX(double x, int index) {
            if (index == 0) {
                StartPoint.x = x;
            } else {
                EndPoint.x = x;
            }
        }

        public void setY(double y, int index) {
            if (index == 0) {
                StartPoint.y = y;
            } else {
                EndPoint.y = y;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

            return (builder.append(String.valueOf(StartPoint.x)).append(" ").append(String.valueOf(StartPoint.y)).append(", ")
                    .append(String.valueOf(EndPoint.x)).append(" ").append(String.valueOf(EndPoint.y))).toString();
        }
    }

    /**
    * Uses the window's aspect ratio to choose a scale factor for the map,
    * and constructs an AffineTransform to scale the shapefile's contents.
    */
    private AffineTransform createTransform(ReferencedEnvelope mapEnvelope, Rectangle imageBounds) {
        double mapWidth = mapEnvelope.getWidth();
        double mapHeight = mapEnvelope.getHeight();
        double imageWidth = imageBounds.getWidth();
        double imageHeight = imageBounds.getHeight();
        double sx = imageWidth / mapWidth;
        double sy = imageHeight / mapHeight;
        double aspectRatio = mapWidth / mapHeight;
        double scale = aspectRatio < 1 ? sy : sx;
        AffineTransform m = new AffineTransform();
        m.scale(scale, scale);
        return m;
    }

    // Create CRS from custom data
    private CoordinateReferenceSystem createCRS() throws FactoryException {

        String wkt = "PROJCS[\"NAD_1983_Michigan_GeoRef_Feet_US\"," +
            "GEOGCS[\"GCS_North_American_1983\"," +
            "DATUM[\"D_North_American_1983\"," +
            "SPHEROID[\"GRS_1980\", 6378137.0, 298.257222101]]," +
            "PRIMEM[\"Greenwich\", 0.0]," +
            "UNIT[\"degree\", 0.017453292519943295]," +
            "AXIS[\"Longitude\", EAST]," +
            "AXIS[\"Latitude\", NORTH]]," +
            "PROJECTION[\"Hotine_Oblique_Mercator\"]," +
            "PARAMETER[\"longitude_of_center\", -86.0]," +
            "PARAMETER[\"latitude_of_center\", 45.30916666666666]," +
            "PARAMETER[\"azimuth\", 337.25555555555593]," +
            "PARAMETER[\"scale_factor\", 0.9996]," +
            "PARAMETER[\"false_easting\", 8355401.583000001]," +
            "PARAMETER[\"false_northing\", -14284780.538]," +
            "PARAMETER[\"rectified_grid_angle\", 337.25555555555593]," +
            "UNIT[\"foot_survey_us\", 0.3048006096012192]," +
            "AXIS[\"X\", EAST]," +
            "AXIS[\"Y\", NORTH]]";

        CRSFactory crsFactory = ReferencingFactoryFinder.getCRSFactory(null);
        CoordinateReferenceSystem crs = crsFactory.createFromWKT(wkt);

        return crs;
    }
```

Upadte: I never added the viewbox code for the SVG (Original)

```
// Calculates the viewbox for the SVG file (Extracts data from map).
    private String calcViewbox() {
        ReferencedEnvelope mapBounds = map.getMaxBounds();
        AffineTransform world2screen = createTransform(mapBounds, imageBounds);

        double minX = mapBounds.getMinX();
        double minY = mapBounds.getMinY();
        double maxX = mapBounds.getMaxX();
        double maxY = mapBounds.getMaxY();
        double width = mapBounds.getWidth(); 
        double height = mapBounds.getHeight();

        Point2D minXY = world2screen.transform(new Point2D.Double(minX, minY), null);
        Point2D widthHeight = world2screen.transform(new Point2D.Double(width, height), null);

        String viewbox = minXY.getX() + " " + minXY.getY() + " " + widthHeight.getX() + " " + widthHeight.getY();

        return viewbox;

    }
```

Update: Made a few changes, one issue that may be causing it is the CRS is not set to EPSG:4326, so I am attempting to convert it to that. However, now it displays nothing (also added viewbox conversion code as well).

also added this to the beginning to flip the map: `System.setProperty("org.geotools.referencing.forceXY", "true");`

```
// Converts map lines to fit in smaller window (mainly for Adobe Illustrator)
    private ArrayList<FeatureLine> convertLines(ArrayList<FeatureLine> lines) {

        ArrayList<FeatureLine> convertedCoords = new ArrayList();

        try {            
            CoordinateReferenceSystem sourceCRS = map.getCoordinateReferenceSystem();
            CoordinateReferenceSystem targetCRS = CRS.decode("EPSG:4326");
            MathTransform transform = CRS.findMathTransform(sourceCRS, targetCRS, true);

            double [] s = new double[4];
            double [] d = new double[4];

            for (FeatureLine coord : lines) {
                    s[0] = coord.StartPoint.x;
                    s[1] = coord.StartPoint.y;
                    s[2] = coord.EndPoint.x;
                    s[3] = coord.EndPoint.y;

                    JTS.xform(transform, s, d);


                 if (coord.StartPoint.x != 0.0) {
                    convertedCoords.add(new FeatureLine(d[0], d[1], d[2], d[3]));
                }
            }
        } catch (FactoryException | TransformException ex) {
            logger.log(Level.SEVERE, "Error occured while converting lines", ex);
        }

        return convertedCoords;
    }


// Calculates the viewbox for the SVG file (Extracts data from map).
    private String calcViewbox() {
        ReferencedEnvelope mapBounds = map.getMaxBounds();
        String viewbox;

        try {
            CoordinateReferenceSystem sourceCRS = map.getCoordinateReferenceSystem();
            if (sourceCRS == null) {
                sourceCRS = CRS.decode("EPSG:102121");
            }
            CoordinateReferenceSystem targetCRS = CRS.decode("EPSG:4326");
            MathTransform transform = CRS.findMathTransform(sourceCRS, targetCRS, true);

            double[] s = new double[]{mapBounds.getMinX(), mapBounds.getMinY(), mapBounds.getMaxX(), mapBounds.getMinY()};
            double[] d = new double[s.length];
            JTS.xform(transform, s, d);
            double width = d[2] - d[0];
            double height = d[3] - d[1];
            viewbox = d[0] + " " + d[1] + " " + width + " " + height;

         } catch (FactoryException | TransformException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            viewbox = "0 0 100 100";
        }

        return viewbox;
    }
```

Comment: A affine transformation allows a 'skew'. See if there's a conformal or similarity transformation instead, or an option on the affine transformation.

Comment: I am trying that now, would you happen to have a link to the AffineTransform doc? can't seem to find it. Also I am trying to use this as a guide, but its confusing and im not doing mine based of static points but any lines that get fed through (the ones above are just samples). http://docs.geotools.org/stable/userguide/tutorial/affinetransform.html

Comment: you could export as SVG and load that into AI

Comment: Thats what I am doing, but the lines are coming out slanted, it works for some maps, but the current ones are not working.

Comment: also found this, didnt see any 'scew' or other option that may be helpful. http://developer.classpath.org/doc/java/awt/geom/AffineTransform-source.html

Comment: http://docs.geotools.org/stable/userguide/library/render/svg.html

Comment: I'm not sure what I am suppose to glean from that link @iant, I added updated code however, maybe pinpointed the issue.

Comment: Actually the updated code wasn't displaying nothing, the map was just super small, like between 1 and 3 pnts in AI.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I've done this in the past, first calculate the size and effective DPI of the output.

```
int width = Math.round(pageSize.getX(MediaSize.INCH)*dpi);
int height = Math.round(pageSize.getY(MediaSize.INCH)*dpi);

if (dpi != standardDpi) {

  double scaleFactor = dpi / standardDpi;
  width = (int) Math.round(width * scaleFactor);
  height = (int) Math.round(height * scaleFactor);
  DpiRescaleStyleVisitor dpiVisitor = new DpiRescaleStyleVisitor(scaleFactor);
  for (Layer layer : mapContent.layers()) {
    if(layer instanceof FeatureLayer) {
      FeatureLayer fLayer = (FeatureLayer)layer;
      dpiVisitor.visit(fLayer.getStyle());
      fLayer.setStyle((Style) dpiVisitor.getCopy());
    }
  }
}
```

Then generate an XML (SVG) document using Batik-svggen:

```
// Create an instance of org.w3c.dom.Document
document = db.getDOMImplementation().createDocument(null, "svg", null);

// Set up the map
SVGGeneratorContext ctx = SVGGeneratorContext.createDefault(document);

ctx.setComment("Generated by GeoTools with Batik SVG Generator");
ctx.setComment("");
SVGGraphics2D g2d = new SVGGraphics2D(ctx, textAsShapes);
```

Then call either your normal renderer (or a new one) to draw the map on that `graphics`.

```
ReferencedEnvelope dataArea = mapContent.getViewport().getBounds();
mapContent.getViewport().setMatchingAspectRatio(true);

mapContent.getViewport().setScreenArea(new Rectangle(Math.round(width), Math.round(height)));
mapContent.getViewport().setBounds(dataArea);

g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);

Rectangle outputArea = new Rectangle(width, height);
g2d.setSVGCanvasSize(outputArea.getSize());
GTRenderer renderer = new StreamingRenderer();
LabelCacheImpl labelCache = new LabelCacheImpl();
Map<Object, Object> hints = renderer.getRendererHints();
if (hints == null) {
  hints = new HashMap<>();
}
hints.put(StreamingRenderer.LABEL_CACHE_KEY, labelCache);
renderer.setRendererHints(hints);
renderer.setMapContent(mapContent);
renderer.paint(g2d, outputArea, dataArea);
```

Finally write that document to a file:

```
  OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
  osw = null;

  osw = new OutputStreamWriter(out, "UTF-8");
  // set the page size
  Element root = g2d.getRoot();
  root.setAttribute("width", "" + pageSize.getX(MediaSize.MM) + "mm");
  root.setAttribute("height", "" + pageSize.getY(MediaSize.MM) + "mm");
  root.setAttribute("viewBox", "0 0 " + width + " " + height);
  // Send to file
  g2d.stream(root, osw);
```

[Full code](https://gitlab.com/snippets/1654234) can be found here.

Comment: Why are you looping through the map layers? does that work on every line or point? or does it just convert the whole map? My code is highly custom and has specific output it needs, I will see if i can use any of this.

Comment: You need to modify the style of each layer if the dpi is non standard (or the lines are too thick for example). The code draws what ever is in the map context

Comment: what would it do to the points of the lines? because they need to be small enough to fit into AI's restricted window (like 16k x 16k) but also big enough to fill that space. I can't tell what your code is actually doing in terms of conversion.

Comment: it fills an A4 page

Comment: ok that might work for size, could be a bit small though:

Equivalent A4 paper dimensions in pixels at 300 DPI and 72 DPI respectively are:

2480 pixels x 3508 pixels (print resolution)
595 pixels x 842 pixels (screen resolution)

Comment: It will handle all standard paper sizes - try A2 if you need more or turn up the DPI higher

Comment: does the DPI need to be those static values or do they have to be based off my map somehow?

Comment: dpi is arbitrary - I usually use 150 or 300 for my printers

Comment: Ok, and what about iniPapers() and those other methods you didn't use, whats the point of those?

Comment: it is intended to be a self contained swing panel that knows about paper, but I gave up on that plan and hard coded A4 in

Comment: ok, so it should run fine without those?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/55539/discussion-between-lloyd-smith-and-iant).

Comment: what's the difference between `DOMImplementation doc = SVGDOMImplementation.getDOMImplementation()` and `DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder()` when creating a document?